# Delete children when parent type changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have this code:

```
class FlexField < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flex_field_values, class_name: 'FlexFieldValue'
  after_save :delete_flex_values

  def delete_flex_values
    if self.field_type != 'list'
      self.flex_field_values.delete_all
    end
  end
```

The goal is to delete all values if the type isn't a list. Now what is happening is that as soon as I set the type to something other than list, none of the children get deleted, but their flex_field_id gets set to null.

How can I really have them deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as :

```
class FlexField < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flex_field_values, class_name: 'FlexFieldValue', dependent: :destroy
  after_save :delete_flex_values

  def delete_flex_values
    if self.field_type != 'list'
      self.flex_field_values.clear
    end
  end
end
```

A brief idea about [`collection.clear`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many):

> Removes every object from the collection. This destroys the associated objects if they are associated with dependent: :destroy, deletes them directly from the database if dependent: :delete_all, otherwise sets their foreign keys to NULL. If the :through option is true no destroy callbacks are invoked on the join models. Join models are directly deleted.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks.  Will accept as answer as soon as I can.